# how customizing scaffolding template and change .cs.t4 file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, t4scaffolding

in MVC when we need a form like below that create a new item of my model, we add a strongly type view on the model with create scaffold template,
model:

```
public class book
{
    [Key]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نام")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نویسنده")]
    public string writer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ناشر")]
    public string publisher { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "سال انتشار")]
    public string year { get; set; }
} `
```

the result is something like this:

```
    @model مدرسه.Models.book
`@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BookStore";
} `
` <h2>BookStore</h2>`
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>book</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.writer)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.writer)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.writer)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.publisher)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.publisher)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.publisher)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.year)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.year)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.year)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
`}`

    <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div> 

 `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
} `
```

this template follow this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding
```

what i need is a knowledge to how change this file and in fact what is this file and what part change the template ?

Comment: what is your problem exactly

Comment: i want to haw my custom template and want to edit  the .cs.t4 file. how to edit ? should i create new file and replace it with old one?

Comment: correct me if iam wrong. you have created a template and then you want to customize the page right

Comment: yes, i want to change the based html code in the .cs.t4 files.

Comment: i found a link to[Modifying the default code generation/scaffolding templates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom layout(template) in the `Shared Folder` in view according to the page requirement.
Then on scaffolding, choose the layout (customized template), model etc and click ok. Thats all

Comment: this solution is choosing a .cshtml file but still the form that it has a default template replaced with `@RenderBody()` . i want to change that default aschema . for example `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div>`   replace with my custom html like    `<div id="myid"><div class="editor-field"><br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div></dive>` for all view that i create with strongly type!

Comment: i want to add some tags in the scaffolding template file (`.cs.t4`)

Comment: you have to create a customize template

Comment: in view folder -> Shared folder -> create a new view file according to your requirement

Comment: i think you misunderstand it or my English is very bad to explain my problem  :-D anyway so much thanks for your try.

Comment: did you use scaffolding before

Comment: Of course! its a default template on MVC always add to my strongly type views!

Comment: then use simple process. first create a page by scaffolding and change the page as you like

Comment: so i need to change for all 45 page i have!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102968/discussion-between-anand-and-mina-a-beigi).

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, it was so hard to find...

Global edit:

> You can modify the original templates, which will globally affect
>   scaffolding across all Visual Studio projects.
>   The original T4 scaffold templates are located in the
>   %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates folder.

Project-specific edit:

> To create project-specific templates, copy the files you want to
>   override from the original T4 scaffold folder to a folder in the
>   ASP.NET MVC Web project called CodeTemplates (it must have this exact
>   name). By convention, the scaffold subsystem first looks in the MVC
>   project’s CodeTemplates folder for a template match.
>
> For this to work, you must precisely replicate the specific sub-folder
>   names and file names you see in the original templates folder.
>
> [image]

Further read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/asp-net-mvc-override-the-default-scaffold-templates